# Is there some other train than Eurostar to go from Lille to London?

Tags: trains, europe, fares, eurostar

Is there a **cheaper**/slower alternative to Eurostar between Lille and London?

Comment: You can get a coach. Look at www.eurolines.com.

Comment: Eurostar prices vary depending on how popular the train is, so there can be a huge difference between an unpopular train booked 3 months out and a popular one for today!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. To go between France and the UK by train, you need to cross the [Channel Tunnel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_tunnel). Only three types of trains cross the Channel tunnel:

- Eurostar high-speed trains carrying passengers
- [Eurotunnel shuttles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurotunnel_Shuttle) carrying vehicles
- Freight trains

The Tunnel will soon open to competition, but the other competitors are likely to be high-speed trains heading to other locations, with similar prices.

I think the cheapest way of crossing the tunnel is [with a bicycle](http://www.eurotunnel.com/uk/traveller-info/vehicles/bicycles-one/), if you have one. It may not be as cheap if you need to rent a bicycle or to buy one in Lille and sell it off in London or if you factor in the expenses along the way.

If you book a little in advance, a bus is likely to be cheaper overall. At least [Eurolines](http://www.eurolines.fr/en/) and [Idbus](http://uk.idbus.com/line/lille-london). The journey time is about 6 hours, as opposed to 1½ hours by train.

You can also investigate ferry crossings. Since the train is faster and more comfortable, ferries can but compete on price.

Comment: So by definition, those Eurotunnel shuttles ARE another train to Eurostar, no? They take cars+passengers together.

Comment: @MarkMayo Technically true but if you are asking about trains, it's because you don't want/can't travel by car, no? The shuttle is not a train *from Lille to London*, it's an alternative to the ferry if you are otherwise traveling by car.

Comment: @MarkMayo Eurotunnel shuttles don't take foot passengers. Technically, I don't know if you can smuggle in by pretending to be a cyclist, but I don't think so. So you need a vehicle not only to go from Lille to Coquelles and Folkestone to London, but also to take that vehicle with you in the train.

Comment: So one can cross with a bicycle, but not without one?  That's funny.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a combination of "classical" trains and ferry.

- Take a local train from Lille to Calais.
- Walk or take a taxi to the
  ferry terminal.
- Cross the channel by ferry to Dover.
- Take a bus from
  the ferry terminal to the train station.
- Take a train to London
  (plenty of options).

A detailed description with up-to date information is available here:
http://www.seat61.com/London-Paris-ferry.htm

This option is only cheaper if you book on shorter notice. If the Eurostar is booked in advance it will be cheaper.

Comment: Bus on the France side of the connection as well, same price or used to be.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a vehicle, you can use the [Eurotunnel Le Shuttle](http://www.eurotunnel.com/uk/home/).

[image]

(onboard, [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ETunnelhoch.jpg))

Passenger vehicles are carried in a car shuttle train, made up of closed wagons.  You can get out and walk along inside, and there are bathrooms, but otherwise it's fairly basic.

[Prices start at £23 each way](http://www.eurotunnel.com/uk/tickets/types/day-and-overnight/)

Comment: Is this really cheaper than the ordinary passenger Eurostar?  I'd expect transporting a vehicle to be much more expensive.

Comment: @NateEldredge prices start at 23 quid per car, according to their site, so depending on the day, and time, yeah, it can be.  I'll update the answer tho, thanks.

Comment: Nate, note also that *Le Shuttle* is a much shorter journey - Ashford to Calais, about 20 minutes - whereas the normal *Eurostar* is from London St. Pancras to Paris Gare du Nord / Lille / Brussels, which is usually north of two hours.

Comment: And you need a car. You have to factor the price of renting a car.

Comment: @IanLudr well only if you don't have your own...or are not already renting one for your holiday anyway.

Comment: @MadHatter Eurostar London-Brussels is under 2 hours, London-Lille is normally 1:20, and Ashford-Lille is sub 1 hour! It's only the London-Paris ones which are over 2 hours

Comment: Fair point, Gagravarr.  I sought only to clarify that it wasn't entirely surprising that a short-hop vehicle passage through the tunnel might be as cheap as, or cheaper than, a (much) longer end-to-end passenger journey.

Comment: The other cost thing is that the *Le Shuttle* is run by the people who own the tunnel, while the *Eurostar* is run by an outside company who has to pay tunnel access charges, and the charging differences are *interesting* enough that there's an EU investigation underway...